# Symbolic integration and numerical integration yield very different results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

This is a topic that has been discussed before, but after reading other posts I could not find a solution that applies for my specific case.

I have the following integral, which I need to evalutate at $n=1,2,3,4...$ and $a=0.1$:

$$ I(n)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} {\rm{d}}x \frac{\Gamma(n,0,2ix)}{(1+iax)^n}.$$

The problem is that `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` seem to yield different results for sufficiently large $n$. Numerical integration with $a=0.1$ leads to

```
a = 1/10;
Table[NIntegrate[Gamma[n, 0, 2 I x]/(1 + I a x)^n, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], {n, 1,6}] // Chop
{5.82505, 9.23019, 42.4493, 117.67, -303.323, -4233.64}
```

However, integrating first and then substituting $a=0.1$ returns the following values:

```
T = Table[Integrate[Gamma[n, 0, 2 I x]/(1 + I a x])^n, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Assumptions->a>0], 
{n, 1, 6}];
a=1/10;
T//N//Chop
{5.82505, 9.22998, 41.7814, 0.951343, -26457.8, -3.06652*10^6}
```

which only agree with numerical integration for $n=1$ and then they become very different. Interestingly, using `Integrate` with $a=0.1$ yields another different set of values:

```
a = 1/10;
TT = Table[Integrate[Gamma[n, 0, 2 I x]/(1 + I a x)^n, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Assumptions -> a > 0], {n, 1, 6}];
TT // N // Chop
{5.82505, 9.23058, 42.4145, 164.712 + 1.19844*10^-9 I, 0, 701973.}
```

All these evaluations occur without mathematica returning any errors. What is happening here? Which values are the correct ones?

Things that I know/ tried:

1. The integral is real, as the imaginary part of the integrand is an odd function of x.
2. `Assumptions->a>0` is necessary, since for arbitrary $a$ the default solution mathematica returns is valid in the complex plane of $a$ minus the positive real axis.
3. From external arguments, the values that I am most inclined to trust are those from exact integration for arbitrary a>0 and then numerical evaluation at a=0.1 (the second set of numbers).
4. The integrand oscillates more and more the higher $n$ is, and I believe `NIntegrate` may have problems getting the right answer for highly oscillatory integrands. However, since it does not return any error I do not know if this is the issue.
5. The problem persists if I use `GammaRegularized(n,0,2ix)` to work with smaller numbers.
6. The problem persists if I increase numerical precision (I am not very familiar with how numerical precision should be managed, maybe I am doing it the wrong way: I increase `$MaxExtraPrecision` and `WorkingPrecision` in `NIntegrate`)

I've read similar posts in which integration methods for `NIntegrate` such as `ExtrapolatingOscillatory` and `DoubleExponentialOscillatory` where suggested, but as far as I know those only work for integrals with infinite range.

Comment: Try `Chop[N[N[T,100]]]`.

Comment: @user293787 That transforms the symbolic integration values into those obtained by numerical integration. How can `Chop` transform something of order $10^6$ into $4233$?

Comment: @user293787 I do not see why Chop has any effect. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuHbz.png)  it is clear the results are different.

Comment: I understand now, this is what happens: the symbolic integration expression for lets say $n=6$  is very, very long. When I evaluated it at $a=0.1$ and used `N`, only 6 digits of precision were kept in each of the many terms and the total evaluation was wrong. With @user293787 command, 100 digits are kept in the evaluation, which drastically changes the result. Numerical integration was right all along.

Comment: The `Chop[N[...]]` is not important, that was just to produce a compact output. The main thing is `N[T,100]`. It seems that there are considerable cancellations among terms that lead to large errors with machine precision `N`. You could look at `N[N[List@@@Expand[T],100]]` to see the cancellations.

Comment: @user293787 that is right. If you care to make your comment into an answer so that other people can easily learn about the mistake, I will accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not `Integrate`, but the numerical evaluation following `Integrate`.

Consider for example `T[[4]]`:

```
T[[4]]
(*
(1/(3 (100 + Pi^2)^3))80000 (48003000 Pi - 
   10520000000 E^20 Pi + 998810 Pi^3 - 315600000 E^20 Pi^3 + 
   5257 Pi^5 - 3156000 E^20 Pi^5 - 10520 E^20 Pi^7 + 
   5260000000 I E^20 ExpIntegralEi[-20 - 2 I Pi] + 
   157800000 I E^20 Pi^2 ExpIntegralEi[-20 - 2 I Pi] + 
   1578000 I E^20 Pi^4 ExpIntegralEi[-20 - 2 I Pi] + 
   5260 I E^20 Pi^6 ExpIntegralEi[-20 - 2 I Pi] - 
   5260 I E^20 (100 + Pi^2)^3 ExpIntegralEi[-20 + 2 I Pi])
*)
```

When one evaluates this numerically, the result depends strongly on how the expression is organized and on what precision is used:

```
N[T[[4]]]
(* 164.712 +1.19844*10^-9 I *)

N[Expand[T[[4]]]]
(* 256. +0. I *)

N[T[[4]],20]
(* 117.670138197013970506+0.*10^-19 I *)
```

The reason is that individual summands are many orders of magnitude larger than the final result:

```
Chop[N[N[List@@Expand[T[[4]]],100]]]
(*
3.03218*10^6
-3.22397*10^17
622685.
-9.5458*10^16
32346.2
-9.42133*10^15
-3.09949*10^14
1.61199*10^17-4.62852*10^6 I
4.7729*10^16-1.37045*10^6 I
4.71066*10^15-135258. I
1.54975*10^14-4449.81 I
1.61199*10^17+4.62852*10^6 I
4.7729*10^16+1.37045*10^6 I
4.71066*10^15+135258. I
1.54975*10^14+4449.81 I
*)
```

Therefore, higher than machine precision is needed to obtain the correct value, which in this case is the one near `117.67`.